# slick carousel not working in ie9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 5 and Slick carousel (orbit is no longer supported). There is a placeholder for Mobile Header that is supposed to display on a mobile device (show-for-small), but should show the Slick carousel on desktop, laptop, etc (hide-for-small). This works on all browsers except ie9.

On IE9, the placeholder is displayed all the time, and the Slick Carousel is not even showing up.
Here is my code....

```
<!-- begin Slick Carousel - 12 column -->
```

```
  <div><img src="img/social-work.jpg" alt="The Master of Social Work program has grown by over 130% since its inception in Fall 2011" title="The Master of Social Work program has grown by over 130% since its inception in Fall 2011" /></div>
</div>
```

```
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x700&text=Mobile Header">

    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is the url: http://cassian.memphis.edu/profiles/fall2014/index.html

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to use Slick Carousel due to a MatchMedia backwards compatibility bug.

I got this error: `SCRIPT5022: matchMedia not present, legacy browsers require a polyfill`

To fix this, I used the matchmedia polyfill.

**Option 1** Install the match-media polyfill npm package, then just require it at the top of your app:

`npm install match-media`

`var MatchMedia = require('match-media');`

**Option 2** (If you don't have a build step): Include this polyfill script on your page, before the slick-carousel script:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webshim/1.15.10/dev/shims/matchMedia.js"></script>`